# exports.__esModule = true; shows as an error in angular 1.6 transpiled code

Tags: angularjs, typescript, babeljs, typescript-typings

I don't know what's the change by babel, but i am trying to resolve from past 2 days :(

Issue is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at app.js:2
```

and I have 102 issues in chrome console due to a single line in my transpiled code i.e.

```
exports.__esModule = true;
```

Following things are used in my project as follows:

```
Angular 1.6
Typescript
Babel@6
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

npm install @types/node

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node

The .d.ts files will define the exports global